# Error with refresh list view

Tags: android, listview

I having problem to refresh the list view. I have a button to approve the checked box in a list view. Once I approve the `listview` is refreshed but the error is when I trying to go back from the refreshed list view, the page keeps loading and the updated list view is not displayed.

my code to process the button click.

```
btnAClaim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_app_claim);
    btnAClaim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyCListActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Confirmation");
            builder.setMessage("Are you to approve all the claims?");

            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    CAdapter adapter = (CListAdapter) lv.getAdapter();
                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        CList cList = adapter.getItem(i);
                        if (cList.isSelected()) {
                            new pClaim("app_claim", null, clList.cId).execute();

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

XML

```html
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_approve_claim"
        android:text="Approve"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

pClaim is Async Task, i'm calling the async task once the button yes is clicked.

private class processClaim extends AsyncTask {

```
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private String message = "Unable to connect.";
    private int success = 0;
    private String action, reason, cID;
```

Comment: Ok you seem to be doing something wrong in your code. 1.You are searching for the selected item in the list and then approving the claim.2 Then you are notifying the list that data has changed .3 .Then you are refreshing the list 4 Starting a new Activity with the current Intent....Is this what you mean to do.?

Comment: yes, when i go back from the new activity, the page keep loading.

Comment: 1. I would wait till processC has executed (In the onPostExecute of my AsyncTask) then refresh my list with notifyDataSetChanged. 2.Call queryCList in the onPostExecute after the i call notifyDataSetChanged. 3.And in queryCList's onPostExecute again call norifyDataSetChanged. 4.Dont create a intent and start the same activity again.

Comment: i will give a try that way.. thank you @DominicD'Souza.

Comment: just check if you are properly showing your progressDialog in onPreExecute and dismissing it in onPostExecute or whereever you are refreshing or loading the data

Answer (score 0):

1. I would wait till `processC` has executed (In the `onPostExecute` of my `AsyncTask`) then refresh my list with `notifyDataSetChanged`.
2. Call `queryCList` in the `onPostExecute` after the i call `notifyDataSetChanged`.
3. And in `queryCList's` `onPostExecute` again call `norifyDataSetChanged`.
4. Don't create a intent and start the same activity again.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you and up vote my answer :P

Comment: the page keeps loading.. but the processC has executed @D

Comment: can you share your entire activity code and xml file

Comment: could you also post your async task

Comment: What i wanted to see is how you are displaying the loader i.e your progressdialog /ProgressBar..You might be showing the progress dialog ..but incorrectly dismissing it

Comment: please check if in onPreExecute you have a method called pDialog.show() and in onPostExecute you have pDialog.dismiss()..

Comment: Also check if you have something like this in queryCList's

Comment: make sure ib onPreExecute you have a method called pDialog.show() and in onPostExecute you have pDialog.dismiss()